# Django - MySQL: 1045 Access Denied for 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I have a Django app using a MySQL database. I created a database `foo`, then created a new user `foo_user`, granted all privileges on `foo.*` to `foo_user`, and flushed privileges.

I can log in from the command-line as `foo_user` and `SHOW GRANTS;` which gives me this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo_user@localhost                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo_user'@'localhost'              |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `foo`.* TO 'foo_user'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can connect from Python using this snippet:

```
import MySQLdb

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'foo_user', 'verysecurepassword', 'foo')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SHOW GRANTS;')
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    for r in results:
        print(r)
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

This prints the privileges for `foo_user` as one would expect.

`settings.py`

```
db_pass = ''
db_pass_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'db.passwd')
with open(db_pass_file, 'r') as dbpf:
    db_pass = dbpf.read()

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        'USER': 'foo_user',
        'PASSWORD': db_pass,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

However, when I try to `makemigrations` I get

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'foo_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I've followed the advice of every SO answer I could find. I've dropped databases and users and then recreated them several times. I can't find anything obviously wrong with it and the error itself is not terribly helpful. My question is: how can I coerce more information out of either MySQL or Django so I can figure out what's going wrong?

ETA: python 3.5.2, Django 1.11.7, mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, running on an EC2 instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an extra newline character at the end of the password being read from file.

The solution was to change

`db_pass = dbpf.read()`

to

`db_pass = dbpf.read().rstrip()`